# How to add a number to each looped element with php?

Tags: php, wordpress

This may seem a really trivial question.

I have a wordpress loop, and I need to number each looped element ascending.

So it will be like this... 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

Is there some php can do this?

```
<?php query_posts( 'posts_per_page=10' ); if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

     <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

          <div id="list-<?php echo number(); ?>">

               <?php get_template_part('item'); ?>

          </div>

     <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Please see the div where I put number() - a made up function/

Thanks

Comment: could you show us your loop ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<?php query_posts( 'posts_per_page=10' ); if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

  <?PHP $i=0; ?>

     <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

          <div id="list-<?php echo $i++; ?">

               <?php get_template_part('item'); ?>

          </div>

     <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

What this basically does, it creates a variable with the value 0. Everytime it goes through the while loop, it adds 1 using ++. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for explaining - very helpful. Will remember this

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php query_posts( 'posts_per_page=10' ); if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php $count = 0; ?>
     <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); $count++; ?>

          <div id="<?php echo number(); ?>" class="item-<?php echo $count ?>">

               <?php get_template_part('item'); ?>

          </div>

     <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

something like this?

Comment: this was also helpful thank you!